# How to show Favorited content in a seperate Activity on FAB click?

Tags: android

[image]

> Here is my Recycler's View Adapter code for the HEART(Toggle Button) :

```
    holder.toggle_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (toggleModel.isFavorite) {
                toggleModel.setFavorite(false);
                Toast.makeText(context, "UNFavorited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                toggleModel.setFavorite(true);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Favorited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, holder.textView.getText().toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            notifyItemChanged(position);

        }
    });
```

> Here is the Layout File for custom_layout.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="100"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
        android:text="This is Arabic Text"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/copybutton"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_content_copy_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/share_txt"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"

            android:id="@+id/whatsApp_txt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/whats" />


        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_btn"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/unfavorite"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

> Here is the Floating Action Button Code :

```
     fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FAB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FavoritedActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
```

> Here is the Model Class code:

```
public class ToggleModel {

int toggled = R.drawable.favorited;
int untoglled = R.drawable.unfavorite;
Boolean isFavorite = false;
String title;

public ToggleModel(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getToggled() {
    return toggled;
}

public int getUntoglled() {
    return untoglled;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setFavorite(boolean favorite) {
    isFavorite = favorite;
}

public boolean isFavorite() {
    return isFavorite;
}
```

}

> After I click the FAB, how can i show the Favorited Contents in a Seperate Activity.
>
> Please provide your valuable Ideas/Suggestions

Comment: save favorite content in database, and then get them in your `FavoritedActivity`

Comment: can I do the same with putExtra and getStringExtra ?

Comment: using database is more reliable, consider the case which user wants to mark the item as unfavourite in your `FavoritedActivity`

Comment: @MohammadSianaki please provide with code or any guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make your `ToggleModel` serializable to pass data through `Intent`

```
public class ToggleModel implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Then find out the favourite items and pass it to next Activity.

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override public void onClick(View view) { 
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FAB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        ArrayList<ToggleModel> favoriteList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ToggleModel model: toggleModelList) {
            if(model.isFavorite())
                favouriteList.add(model);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FavoritedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("FAVOURITE_LIST", (Serializable) favouriteList);
        startActivity(intent); 
    } 
});
```

Then in your `FavoritedActivity`'s `onCreate` try to get value from Intent.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite);

    ArrayList<ToggleModel> favoriteList = (ArrayList<ToggleModel>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("FAVOURITE_LIST"); 

    //Your favorite list is here. Now call the adapter and attach with recyclerview to show this

    ...
}
```

If you want to get only the text e.g **title**, then follow this:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override public void onClick(View view) { 
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FAB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        ArrayList<String> favoriteList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ToggleModel model: toggleModelList) {
            if(model.isFavorite())
                favouriteList.add(model.getTitle());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FavoritedActivity.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("FAVOURITE_LIST", favouriteList);
        startActivity(intent); 
    } 
});
```

And then in `FavoritedActivity`'s `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite);

    ArrayList<String> favoriteList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("FAVOURITE_LIST"); 

    //Your favorite list of title is here. Now call the adapter and attach with recyclerview to show this

    ...
}
```

Comment: I implemented the Log like this : intent.putExtra("FAVOURITE_LIST", favoriteList);
              Log.e("FAVVV :", favoriteList.toString());
              startActivity(intent);

Comment: I am getting this LogCat : com.zedapps.elon.ToggleModel@e619734, com.zedapps.elon.ToggleModel@1d7695d,  , How can i get the Text

Comment: Check my updated answer if you want to get only the title part.